# How to get download link from web page in android

Tags: android

I new to android. I am trying to get download url from web page in android. For this I have used JSoup library to parse HTML tags and to get that download URL. But I unable to get that download URL from that web page. I got # alone instead of that URL. When I inspect that page and I can able to see download URL. I copied and hit in browser address bar. File is downloaded properly. But when I view page source "#" is displayed in 'href' source. Is this possible to get that download URL from android. If possible Please help me to get the download url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: pl share the code and you url you are accessing.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarelam I unable to provide url here. Because it is official one.

Comment: that all depends on specific web page. Nobody can tell you how to parse specific URL, if you don't show it. There might be set OnClickListener on that `<a href/>`, which redirects browser to download url for example.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found answer for my question. Here is my answer. I wrote a java script code to get the url by using tag attribute "id". Then evaluated that function via  android.

**Javascript code:**

```
(function() { return document.getElementById("id").getAttribute("href"); })();
```

**android code**

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("/*javascript function goes here*/",new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {

                Log.d("LogName", s); // Returns the value from the function

        });
```